# Map pans and zooms when opening info window

Tags: angular-google-maps

when I click on a marker the map always re-pans and zooms to the initial state.  Not such a big deal for a single marker but if I start with a cluster, zoom in and then click on a marker there is the problem.  It zooms out, reclusters and then pops up the window.  Anybody come across this issue?

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
var loc = { latitude: item.Latitude, longitude: item.Longitude };
                     var marker = { location: loc, label: item.Label, id: item.Id, value: item.Value,showWindow:false };
                     markers.push(marker);
                     marker.onClick = function () {
                         if ($scope.$$phase || $scope.$root.$$phase) {
                             this.model.showWindow = true;
                         } else {
                             var self = this;
                             $scope.$apply(function() {
                                 self.model.showWindow = true;
                             });
                         }
                     };
```

And the markup.  This is in another directive that allows me to just keep a list of different layer types:

```
 '<markers models="mylayer.locations" coords="\'location\'" doRebuildAll="true" idKey="\'id\'" doCluster="true" fit="true" options="mylayer.options" click="\'onClick\'">' +
                     '<windows show="\'showWindow\'" doRebuildAll="false" disableAutoPan="true" data-ng-if="mylayer.options.clickable" ng-cloak>' +
                            '<div>hello</div>' +
                     '</windows>' +
                  '</markers>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem happened when updating from version 1.1.0 of angular-google-maps.js to version 1.1.4.  Reverted and it works fine now.

Comment: Did you open an issue for this?

Comment: I notified the developer and he is looking into it